# how to filter objects in angular material autocomplete

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am trying to create a filter on an angular material autocomplete form input. I am not able to filter values when I have an array of objects.

I have forked the example from the angular material documentation and modified it to try and filter objects. Other then that, it is largely unchanged from the documentation example.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hu2zew)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to filter on the city names you have to specify the city_name property.  So you just have to adjust your filter accordingly

```
return this.options.filter(option => 
    option.city_name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) || 
    option.city_num.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to filter all values? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes - you will just have to do an or condition `return this.options.filter(option => 
      option.city_name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
      option.city_num.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    );`